# Loop through int array, return True if following int is equal to current

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Given a list of ints, return True if the array contains a 3 next to a 3 somewhere.

has_33([1, 3, 3]) → True

has_33([1, 3, 1, 3]) → False

has_33([3, 1, 3]) → False

First Approch:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)):
        return nums[i] == nums[i+1] ==3
```

Could someone explain me what's wrong with this approach, I see that this code is returning True only if all the elements in  a list are true.

Second Approach:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)):
        if(nums[i] == nums[i+1] ==3):
            return True
```

The second approach satisfies my question.

What is the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: Your first method returns on its first loop iteration. So it only checks for `i=0`. The rest of the loop is never performed because your function has already returned.

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev What if the number 33 is in the list?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the difference is rather obvious. In the first case, you inconditionnaly return the result of expression `nums[i] == nums[i+1] ==3`, whatever the value of this expression is. This actually means that you always return on the very first iteration, so your code could as well be written as

```
def has_33(nums):
    if len(nums):
        return nums[0] == nums[1] ==3
```

In the second case, you only return if the expression is true, so the iteration goes on until either you explicitely return (found a match) or the iteration naturally terminates and you've found nothing (in which case the function will implicitely return `None`).

Unrelated, but your code (second version) can be improved in quite a few ways. First point: Python "for" loop are of the "foreach" kind - you iterate on the sequence elements, not indices. If you don't need the indice, the proper way is

```
for item in iterable:
    do_something_with(item)
```

no need for `range(len(xxx))` and indexed access here.

If you do need both the item and the index, then `enumerate()` is your friend - it yields `(index, item)` tuples:

```
for index, item in enumerate(sequence):
    print("item at {} is {}".format(index, item))
```

Now for your current need - geting `(item, nextitem)` pairs -, there's still another solution: `zip(seq1, seq2)` + slicing:

```
for item, nextitem in zip(sequence, sequence[1:]):
    print("item: {} - nextitem : {}".format(item, nextitem))
```

and finally, if what you want is to check if at least one item in a sequence satisfies a condition, you can use `any()` with a predicate:

```
def has_33(nums):
    return any((item == nextitem == 3) for item, nextitem in zip(nums, nums[1:]))
```

Another solution could be to turn `nums` into a string and look for the literal string `"33"` in it:

```
def has_33(nums):
    return "33" in "".join(str(x) for x in nums)
```

but I'm not sure this will be more efficient (you can use `timeit` to find out by yourself).

Answer (score 0):

In your first approach, you will return the value of

```
return nums[i] == nums[i+1] == 3 #Where i = 0 since it returns 
first iteration.
return nums[0]==nums[1] == 3 #If nums = [0,3,3]
return false # would be your result. But it would never check the next pair of values.
```

In your second approach, you will return the value

```
return true #If the if-statement is satisfied
```

The return function, will end the function call when called. Therefore, if being called in a for-loop without an if-statement, it will be called for the first iteration. If there is an if-statement and the iteration passes through the if-statement, it will return and end the loop at that iteration. Basically, the return function ends the function call and returns the value given.